# Find the crashing assembly instruction from core dump on Linux

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, coredump

If I load the crashing program and the core dump into `gdb`, it shows me a stack trace and crash point as below.

```
Core was generated by `./cut --output-d=: -b1,1234567890- /dev/fd/63'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  is_printable_field (i=1234567890) at src/cut.c:266
266   return (printable_field[n] >> (i % CHAR_BIT)) & 1;
(gdb) bt
#0  is_printable_field (i=1234567890) at src/cut.c:266
#1  set_fields (fieldstr=0x7ffccb0561c4 "") at src/cut.c:533
#2  main (argc=4, argv=0x7ffccb055cf8) at src/cut.c:865
```

Is there any means to know the exact assembly instruction that caused the segfault?

Comment: @terencehill Disassembly of a high level line may yield multiple assembly instructions.

Comment: maybe you can try `layout asm` and step until the program crash.

Comment: If there is not a requirement that it should be done from gdb, then, running under the `valgrind` will help

Comment: If an answer solved your problem or helped you, please consider to accept it, see also:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 8):

One possibility is to set:

```
(gdb)layout asm
```

When GDB stops the corresponding assembly line is pointed.

Example:

```
   │0x7ffff7aa441d <strtok+45>      je     0x7ffff7aa44d6 <strtok+230>                                                                                       │
   │0x7ffff7aa4423 <strtok+51>      mov    %rsi,%rax                                                                                                         │
  >│0x7ffff7aa4426 <strtok+54>      mov    (%rax),%cl                                                                                                        │
   │0x7ffff7aa4428 <strtok+56>      test   %cl,%cl                                                                                                           │
   │0x7ffff7aa442a <strtok+58>      je     0x7ffff7aa4454 <strtok+100>


Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7aa4426 in strtok () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb)
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`disassemble`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Machine-Code.html#index-disassemble-568) GDB command. Also perhaps use [`x/i`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Memory.html#index-x-_0040r_007b_0028examine-memory_0029_007d-619) on `$rip` (the program counter on x86-64)

However, in your case, assuming the code is in C (not C++ with some `operator []`), the only possible culprits are the `printable_field` pointer, or the `n` index.

Consider also using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and/or compiling (in addition of `-g -Wall` options to a recent [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler) with [`-fsanitize=`...](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Debugging-Options.html) options, notably `-fsanitize=address` or `-fsanitize=undefined`...

Comment: Disassembly of a high level line may yield multiple assembly instructions. How do I know which one the culprit is?

Comment: Yes, I can very well see that `i` has been set to a very high value. But, is there any means to pinpoint the faulting instruction that generates SIGSEGV?

Comment: The GDB `disassemble` command is nearly useless on a large function. I'm about 75 pages into the function, and I don't know if I accidentally missed `==>`, or if its coming up. What genius thought it was a great idea to always disassemble form the start of the function; and not provide a `disassemble .` (where dot is "here").